Find the segment $MN$ if $BM = 5$ in the triangle below
Find $MN$ if $BM =5$
(Answer: $10$)

I try:
$\angle AMB = 90^o -\alpha$
$ \angle MNA  = 180^o - 2\alpha - \theta = 180^o -(2\alpha+\theta)$
$\angle CNM = \theta+2\alpha$
$\angle MNC = 180^o -(90^o-\alpha+\theta) = 90^o+\alpha - \theta$
$ \therefore \angle NMC = 90^o +\alpha - (90^o -3\alpha) = 4\alpha$

It's maybe a subjective impression, but having $BC$ as a horizontal line might increase understanding about this image a lot.

How did you go from 90-α+θ=θ+2α+θ to 3α+2θ

As pointed in a comment to some other of your questions, you should expose your procedure in words. This would help the reader understand what you have done (and may also help you spot some errors!). It is easy to verify by construction that any $\alpha$ and $\theta$ will do, provided that $3\alpha$ and $\theta$ are complementary angles.

@Peta Can you recheck your work? At the level of the problems you're posting, it's rare that you can quickly angle chase an exact value. In particular, there are numerous errors in the line of $ \angle BMN + \theta = \angle CNM + \theta$. $\quad$ I agree with dfnu that "any $\alpha, \theta$ will do as long as $ 3 \alpha + \theta = 90^\circ$, and that's my conclusion after fixing the errors in your work.

@NirbhayKrishnan It was a mistake but I've already fixed it

@CalvinLin Thanks for the heads up..I've already fixed the errors

A path with Euclidean Geometry


Produce $CB$ to $D$ so that $DB \cong BM$, and produce $AC$ to $E$ so that $ME \cong NE$.
Using the fact that $3\alpha + \theta = 90^\circ$, and Exterior Angle Theorem on $AMN$, show that $\measuredangle MNC = \measuredangle AMB =90^\circ-\alpha$.
Since $ADM$ and $MNE$ are both isosceles, by 2. they are in fact similar (AAA criterion).
Use angle chasing to show that $\measuredangle MAC = \measuredangle MEC = 2\alpha$, and therefore that $AM \cong EM$.
Obtain your thesis from the congruence $ADM \cong MNE$ (point 3. and 4.).


Very nice identifying the isosceles triangles to make the argument.

Excelent  thanks

Let's start with noting that $\theta=90^\circ-3\alpha$. Applying the law of sines to $\triangle AMN$:$$\frac{MN}{\sin 2\alpha} = \frac{AM}{\sin (90^\circ+\alpha)}, MN=\frac{BM\sin 2\alpha}{\sin (90^\circ+\alpha)\sin \alpha}=\frac{5 \cdot 2 \sin \alpha \cos \alpha}{\cos \alpha\sin \alpha}=10$$

Thank you for the solution. Would a more geometric resolution with auxiliary lines be possible?

@CalvinLin: thanks for pointing that out! The trig solution will still work and the OP is aware of the miscalculations.

In fact, since it has been proved that $\widehat{CNM}=\widehat{BMA}=\widehat{ADB}$, that implies $ANMD$ cyclic; as $AM$ is angle bisector of $\angle CAD$, we get $MN=MD=2BM$, done.
